# Group by in doctrine mongodb

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, group-by, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to make a group by in mongodb with doctrine.
I have made sentence with createQuery (doctrine) but not with MongoDB.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQuery("Select sum(p.cantidad) FROM Application\Entity\ConjuntoProductos p where p.cesta=:cesta group by p.cesta");
    $qb->setParameter('cesta', $idCesta);
    $results=$qb->getResult();
```

I need to do in MongoDB.

Thank You.

Comment: Check this help: http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

Comment: Thanks, but the parameters for: ->group(array(), array('count' => 0))  which are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
     $results = $qb
        ->group ( array (
            'id' => 1
        ), array (
            'total' => 0
        ) )->reduce ( 'function ( curr, result ) { result.total += curr.cantidad;}' )

        ->field ( 'cesta.id' )->equals ( $idCesta )
        ->getQuery ()->execute ();
```